# Python rpy2 and quantmod examples

Tags: python, r, runtime-error, rpy2, quantmod

Python programming language has helped me a lot in developing financial data analysis applications. Alternatively, there is the R for data analysis too, which has dedicated financial data analysis packages, for example: [quantmod](http://www.quantmod.com/).

Now, that there is [rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.3/html/overview.html) to interface between both these languages(i.e. Python & R). I would like to prototype some financial data analysis applications using the power of python with the quantmod package.

By now, I have spent several hours searching the internet for some quick starter code examples in python programming language that uses rpy2(python package) and calls quantmod functions. So far, I have not been successful in finding any suitable material... apart from the rpy2 & quantmod documentations.

Therefore the question is as follows =>

1. Does any one know of a suitable resource/s to get me started with python & quantmod using rpy2?
2. Alternatively, can some one post simple example/s of pythonic code that calls quantmod functions using rpy2?

Here is an attempt of mine in implementing a prototype using rpy2 & quantmod:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

sta = {"skeleton.TA": "skeleton_dot_TA", "skeleton_TA": "skeleton_uscore_TA"}
quantmod = importr('quantmod', robject_translations = sta)

IBM = quantmod.getSymbols("IBM")
```

Problem with the above code(quantmodplot.py) is that it produces "RuntimeError" as follows:

```
 As of 0.4-0, ‘getSymbols’ uses env=parent.frame() and
 auto.assign=TRUE by default.

 This  behavior  will be  phased out in 0.5-0  when the call  will
 default to use auto.assign=FALSE. getOption("getSymbols.env") and 
 getOptions("getSymbols.auto.assign") are now checked for alternate defaults

 This message is shown once per session and may be disabled by setting 
 options("getSymbols.warning4.0"=FALSE). See ?getSymbol for more details
Error in as.character(sc[[1]]) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quantmodplot.py", line 6, in <module>
    IBM = quantmod.getSymbols("IBM")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2-2.3.6-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 86, in __call__
    return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2-2.3.6-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 35, in __call__
    res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in as.character(sc[[1]]) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated...

Comment: `RRuntimeError` is often raised when the error is originating from R... is `getSymbols("IBM")` working at all when in R ?

Comment: `getSymbols("IBM")` is working in R, for example I'm able to execute the below script in R & it works fine:
`require('quantmod')`  
`getSymbols('IBM', src='google', from='2013-01-01')`  
`candleChart(to.minutes10(IBM), theme="white", up.col="grey", dn.col="black", TA=NULL)`  
`addMACD(10,35,5)`

Answer (score 3):

The `getSymbols()` bit seems a little unconventional (R already has the functions `get()` and `mget()`).

The problem occurs in `importDefaults()` (package `Defaults`), itself a strange beast: it goes back 2 calling frames up the stack, in order to fetch the name of the function calling (so here "getSymbols").

The function `getSymbols()` in `quantmod` contains the code:

```
function (Symbols = NULL, env = parent.frame(), reload.Symbols = FALSE, 
    verbose = FALSE, warnings = TRUE, src = "yahoo", symbol.lookup = TRUE, 
    auto.assign = getOption("getSymbols.auto.assign", TRUE), 
    ...) 
{
    # (...code cut out...)
    importDefaults("getSymbols")
```

The call `importDefaults("getSymbols)` goes up the calling stack in order to get the symbol of the calling function, that is "getSymbols".

In rpy2, an R function called (from Python) does not have a symbol in an R enclosing frame (since the enclosing frame is Python). In a way it is like an anonymous function for R. This could probably be improved in the high-level interface `rpy2.robjects`, but I never found the time to work on it.

A workaround is to make sure that the function has a calling frame and a symbol:

```
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import ListVector
base = importr("base")
base.do_call("getSymbols", ListVector({'Symbols':"IBM"}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Today, I have also tested the following approach... i.e. explicitly calling `rpy2.robjects` in-order to call R script within python. Example of such an approach are lines `In [5]:` `In [6]:` in the below python script. Interestingly, this approach seems to work:

```
In [1]: from rpy2.robjects import r
In [2]: from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
In [3]: sta = {"skeleton.TA": "skeleton_dot_TA", "skeleton_TA": "skeleton_uscore_TA"}
In [4]: quantmod = importr('quantmod', robject_translations = sta)
In [5]: IBM = r("getSymbols('IBM', src='google', from='2013-01-01')")
 As of 0.4-0, ‘getSymbols’ uses env=parent.frame() and
 auto.assign=TRUE by default.

 This  behavior  will be  phased out in 0.5-0  when the call  will
 default to use auto.assign=FALSE. getOption("getSymbols.env") and 
 getOptions("getSymbols.auto.assign") are now checked for alternate defaults

 This message is shown once per session and may be disabled by setting 
 options("getSymbols.warning4.0"=FALSE). See ?getSymbol for more details

In [6]: r("candleChart(IBM, TA=NULL)")
Out[6]: <RS4 - Python:0xae3a14c / R:0xaae455c>
```

However, running such a python script => `quantmod.getSymbols("IBM")` produces `RRuntimeError`!
Hence, the primary problem still remains unresolved!

Well, here are some environmental details regarding my development machine:

```
OS: Ubuntu Linux 12.04
Python version: '2.7.3'
Python package: rpy2-2.3.6
R version: 3.0.0 (2013-04-03)
R package: quantmod_0.4-0
```