# Does Python has a similar library like quantmod in R that can download financial statement data?

Tags: python, r, quantmod

Does Python has a similar library like quantmod in R that can download financial statement data? I want to download the historical revenue of each stock in Python. Can someone give me a hint? Thanks.

Comment: With urrlib2 you can download anything

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes a lot of them, [zipline](https://github.com/quantopian/zipline), [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) and even [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/date_demo1.html) can download data from Yahoo Finance. I recommend you use pandas:

```
>>> from pandas_datareader.data import DataReader
>>> from datetime import datetime

>>> goog = DataReader("GOOG",  "yahoo", datetime(2000,1,1), datetime(2012,1,1))
>>> goog["Adj Close"]
Date
2004-08-19     49.982655
2004-08-20     53.952770
2004-08-23     54.495735
2004-08-24     52.239197
2004-08-25     52.802086
...
```

Comment: Ooh, I had forgotten pandas can do that.

Comment: You can also try QSTK package `http://wiki.quantsoftware.org/index.php?title=QuantSoftware_ToolKit` There was a entire free online course using this, goolge, Computational Investing, Part I (coursera)

Answer (score 3):

Rather than build your own system with urllib2, [you can use `rpy2` to load the actual quantmod package through R into Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16599717/python-rpy2-and-quantmod-examples). It's somewhat convoluted, but it'll get you the exact quantmod data you're looking for.

Comment: I tried using rpy2 before and as you say found it convoluted.  I now use python to write a CSV, then load that in R.  OP here can do the opposite and download the data in R, write to a CSV, and then use it from python.

Comment: Or just use pandas :)

Comment: seems like pandas can't give you Japan exchange data.